# Find angle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I'm currently designing a game and I've bumped into a problem that primarily involves trigonometry.

The player holds a camera at a point that I want to aim at another point, I have all the programming down except in the function for the camera or the gun (to avoid confusion with the viewspace as being the camera). All I have is parameters for the mouse position x,y and this code:

```
var pos=this.gameObject.phy.pos
this.angle=Math.atan((x-pos.x)/(y-pos.y))*57.2957795
```

`pos.x/pos.y` being the player's own coordinates

Ideally I want the angle to be in degrees, hence the `*57`, I don't have much experience working with radians.

I'd also like the angle to be in standard position with `0*` facing directly left, and going counterclockwise or clockwise producing a negative angle.

What's the proper ratio for this?

Comment: The trick to using radians is to not actually care what the number is, but what it's ratio to 2 Pi is. For example, Pi is one half of 2 Pi, so that's one half of a circle. This is quite the same as 180 degrees is one-half of 360 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When both the relative X and Y are negative, the signs will cancel, yielding the same result as when the relative X and Y are both positive. For that reason, it might give you an angle pointing the opposite direction.

The way around this is to use `Math.atan2`, which adjusts the angle according to the sign as necessary. It takes two arguments: the relative Y and the relative X. So:

```
this.angle=Math.atan2(y-pos.y, x-pos.x)/Math.PI*180;
```

Comment: thanks! got it with `this.angle=Math.atan2(pos.y-y, x-pos.x)*57.2957795;`